# Prove that if $E$ is measurable, then $m(E) = m_{*}(A) + m^{*}(E-A)$ for any $A \subseteq E$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Basically what the title says: Prove that if $E$ is measurable, then $m(E) = m_{*}(A) + m^{*}(E-A)$ for any $A \subseteq E$. Here $m_*$ and $m^*$ are the interior and exterior measures, respectively. Also, $m(E)$ is the Lebesgue measure. Obviously, this is true whenever $A$ itself is measurable since $m_*(A) = m^*(A)$ and we can apply Carantheodory's Criterion. However, I cannot seem to do the general case.